# Java android fix Failed to crunch file

Tags: java, android

When I added to my project     `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'`
and sync project I see this :

```
Error:Failed to crunch file C:\Users\ElteGps 022\Desktop\smok mobile\SMOKMobile-master-82c8589239c26646d1b81cc71810dbd11f2743f51\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\25.2.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png into C:\Users\ElteGps 022\Desktop\smok mobile\SMOKMobile-master-82c8589239c26646d1b81cc71810dbd11f2743f51\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_textfield_search_default_mtrl_alpha.9.png
```

This is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smok.maps"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile files('libs/android-support-v4.jar')
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.6.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/osmbonuspack_v4.9.jar')
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.2-javadoc.jar')
    compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-4.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar')

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
 aaptOptions
   {
   cruncherEnabled = false
   }
```

**FYI**

Call `buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"` instead of `buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"`

- **compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'**
- call  **compileSdkVersion 25** instead of **19** .

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restarts and Sync`** your IDE

Comment: When I use a buildToolsVersion "25.0.1" instead of buildToolsVersion "24.0.3" I see this same error . when I added aaptOptions in android I see this same error . I edit my post

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka good question , Your `design:25.2.0` is not compatible with `24.0.3`

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka if the same problem arise, Change your SDK  Location

Comment: I have to dowload a new sdk or what ?

Comment: @KrzysztofPokrywka okay . At first create a new project with version 25

Comment: Ok but this project is import by project in eclipse . I want to migrate to Android Studio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136819/discussion-between-krzysztof-pokrywka-and-intellij-amiya).